Symmetric differentiation of real functions
Let a function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

$f$ is symmetrically continuous in $x$ if $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} [f(x+h)-f(x-h)] = 0$.


$f$ is symmetrically differentiable in $x$ if $f'_s(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + h) - f(x - h)}{2h}$ exists finite.
$f$ is symmetrically differentiable twice in $x$ if $f''_s(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x + h) - 2f(x) + f(x - h)}{h^2}$ exists finite.

Now: $f$ twice differentiable --> $f$ differentiable --> $f$ continue (in classic sense)
$\hspace{2cm} \downarrow$ $\hspace{5cm} \downarrow$ $\hspace{3cm} \downarrow$
$f$ twice sym.differentiable $\hspace{0.5cm}$ $f$ sym.differentiable --> $f$ sym.continue
My question is: if twice symmetric differentiability implies symmetric differentiability?

My attempt: Suppose $f''_s(x)$ exists finite.
Then $\dfrac{f(x + h) - f(x - h)}{2h}=\dfrac{h}{2}\biggl[\dfrac{f(x + h) - 2f(x) + f(x - h)}{h^2}+\dfrac{  2f(x) -2 f(x - h)}{h^2}\biggr]=\dfrac{h}{2}\biggl[\dfrac{f(x + h) - 2f(x) + f(x - h)}{h^2}\biggr]+\dfrac{  f(x) - f(x - h)}{h}\longrightarrow0\cdot f''_s(x)+\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{  f(x) - f(x - h)}{h}$
And now?

Hint: every odd function is symmetrically differentiable twice at $x = 0$, but it is easy to make it not symmetrically differentiable.
